# Getting Array value in a dictionary swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am trying to get key and value in a `Dictionary` while I am able to the key and map it to a dictionary, I am unable to get the value which is an array.

`var dict = [String: [String]]`

I was able to get the key as an array which is what I want like:

`var keyArray = self.dict.map { $0.key }`

How can I get the value which is already an array

Comment: Values as an array? Give an example.

Comment: var values:  [String]

Comment: can you elaborate this line ? how can I get the value which is already an array

Comment: @jawadAli dictionaries are key value pairs, the `key`  is a string and the `value` is an array of strings

Comment: yes ... you can access each string array using map ... but if you want to merge all those arrays to one array you will use flatMap

Comment: both are the approaches ... depending what you want to achieve further ...

Comment: Unrelated but `dict.map { $0.key }` is the same as `Array(dict.keys)` which avoids the loop (under the hood)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flatMap` if you want to flatten the result you get when you use `map` which is of type `[[String]]`.

```
let valueArray = dict.flatMap { $0.value } // gives `[String]` mapping all the values
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you get each string count Array

```
var dict = [String: [String]]()
        
let countOfEachString = dict.map { $0.value }.map{ $0.count }
```

Each `value` is a `string` array .. so to access each array you need to use map again